# Separate panes / or style maximum gridlines in Highstock

Tags: highcharts

I built a widget with multiple y Axes very similar to the official sample here: http://www.highcharts.com/stock/demo/candlestick-and-volume

I'm trying to have some sort of visual separation between the chart panes, either by

- applying a special style to the maximum grid line for each pane, or
- adding a horizontal line in the whitespace between the panes

The only approach i got working is using `PlotLines`, but I'd rather have a separator that's independent of zoom levels. Any ideas on how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [Renderer](http://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/Renderer.path) to draw a path between y axes.

```
function drawSeparator() {
  let separator = this.separator;
  const options = this.options.chart.separator;

  if (options && options.enabled) {
    if (!separator) {
      this.separator = separator = this.renderer.path({
        d: 'M 0 0',
        'stroke-width': options.width === undefined ? 1 : options.width,
        stroke: options.color || 'black'
      }).add();
    }

    const topAxisBottom = this.yAxis[0].top + this.yAxis[0].height;
    const bottomAxisTop = this.yAxis[1].top;
    const y = topAxisBottom + (bottomAxisTop - topAxisBottom) / 2;

    separator.attr({
      d: `M 0 ${y} L ${this.chartWidth} ${y}`
    });
  }
}
```

Call the method on load/redraw event

```
chart: {
  events: {
    load: drawSeparator,
    redraw: drawSeparator
  },
  separator: {
    enabled: true,
    width: 3,
    color: 'blue'
  }
},
```

You can modify the path's d attribute, the path starts from `axis.left` and stops on `axis.left + axis.width`

#### Live example and output

http://jsfiddle.net/L11uqxgq/

[image: axis separator]